# Tomcat: trace all (even catched) exceptions

Tags: java, exception, tomcat, primefaces, trace

is it possible to trace all exceptions in Tomcat server (or, in general, JVM)?

Thanks for all!

P.S. I need it because exception occurs in 
[`org.primefaces.application.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest()`](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/java/org/primefaces/application/PrimeResourceHandler.java) and a trivial message is printed (line 79)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Start tomcat using that:

```
./catalina jpda start
```

And then connect using the eclipse debugger, as described here:

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing#Q1

When for example Eclipse is connected, go to the Breakpoints panel, there will be a button "Add Java Exception breakpoint" if you set java.lang.Exception or java.lang.RuntimeException there, all the subclasses will be caught.

Answer (score 3):

Globally the logging is either configured in

```
${catalina.base}/conf/logging.properties file or {java.home}/lib/logging.properties
```

You can change the trace level by uncommenting the following property and setting it to ALL.

```
org.apache.catalina.level=ALL
```

More Info: [Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Using_java.util.logging_%28default%29)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such a feature in the JVM.

I believe you wish so figure out the reason why that exception is being thrown, right? I would use an IDE such as Netbeans, include that library as a dependency, download the sources, and place a breakpoint on that line. Then, through the standard debugger, I would scan the stack trace when the breakpoint is hit to look for clues.