# How to disable spring security logging

Tags: tomcat, logging, spring-security

I'm using Tomcat for servlet container, and i must check catalina.out log to debug everyday. But when an anonymous user tried to login, the Spring Security interceptor throws exception, it floods catalina.out logfile. The log like this:

```
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:327)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:197)
at org.springframework.flex.security3.EndpointInterceptor.preProcess(EndpointInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.flex.core.MessageInterceptionAdvice.invoke(MessageInterceptionAdvice.java:62)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.invoke(ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.java:124)
... 52 more
```

How to disable Spring Security logging in Tomcat?

Answer (score 4):

You will see AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException in the logs when the log level is set to DEBUG and if you do not have AnonymousAuthenticationFilter in your filter chain.

See [FAQ](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#auth-exception-credentials-not-found).

So I am assuming you are using traditional bean configuration in your security application context instead of namespace configuration. If you want to get rid of the exception you can add an anonymousAuthenticationFilter to your application context as described in the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/anonymous.html#anonymous-config)

Alternatively, you can turn the log level of

```
org.springframework.security.level=INFO
```

in tomcat as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264133/tomcat-trace-all-even-catched-exceptions).